# How could I add periodically a new element to an array so it appears after every 500th element?

Tags: python, numpy

If I have an array (column) that has 500k elements (numbers only), how could I be able to add a new element after every 500th element? The new number should be the average of the neighbor elements.

E.g.: between elements 499 and 500 a new element with a value of (value of 499+ value of 500)/2 and so on.

```
a=np.array(h5py.File('/Users/Ad/Desktop//H5 Files/3D.h5', 'r')['Zone']['TOp']['data'])
output = np.column_stack((a.flatten(order="C"))
np.savetxt('merged.csv',output,delimiter=',')
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The best way to achieve this is probably creating a generator and create a new array with that generator. Inserting into a numpy array isn't really possible, as arrays have a fixed size, so you'd need to create a new array for each insert, wich is very expensive. Using a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3.10/glossary.html#term-generator) you'd only need to iterate through the array once and create only one new array.

```
def insert_every_500th_element(np_array):
    prev = None
    for idx, value in enumarate(np_array):
        if idx != 0 and idx % 500 == 0: # we're at the 500th element - yield (499th + 500th value)/2
            yield (prev+value)/2
        yield value

a=np.array(h5py.File('/Users/Ad/Desktop//H5 Files/3D.h5', 'r')['Zone']['TOp']['data'])
a = np.fromiter(insert_every_500th_element(a), float)
output = np.column_stack((a.flatten(order="C"))
np.savetxt('merged.csv',output,delimiter=',')
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two solutions, one in which each 500th element is edited to the new value, and another where a new value is inserted in to the array. Note that this cannot happen in-place so you must overwrite the existing array.

```py
# if you want to edit each 500th element to a new value
iter_num = 500; i=iter_num
while i < len(array):
    array[i] = (array[i]+array[i-1])/2
    i += iter_num

# if you want a new element inserted in position 500
iter_num = 500; i=iter_num
while i < len(array):
    array = np.insert(array, i, (array[i]+array[i-1])/2)
    i += iter_num + 1
```

Comment: The latter gets off by one index for each item previously inserted. The index at which you insert needs to increment by one more, to account for the item you just inserted.

Comment: You're right. When inserting a new element the `i` parameter should be incremented like so: `i += iter_num+1`. Edited to reflect the new element added

Answer (score 1):

To take advantage of NumPy's vectorization power, you could approach this as a matrix operation: Turn `a` into a matrix where the number of columns equals your desired interval for insertion. Then the relevant left neighbors are the rightmost column, and the relevant right neighbors are the leftmost column with each value shifted upward one row. So you can calculate their means and append those as a new column, then unravel ro return a flat array.

```py
import numpy as np

def insert_means(a, n):
    """Insert means of neighboring values at every n-th point of a flat array a."""
    m = len(a) // n  # number of rows (assuming len(a) is a multiple of n)
    a = a.reshape((m, n))  # matrix with m rows and n columns
    left_neighbors = a[:, -1]
    right_neighbors = np.roll(a[:, 0], shift=-1)
    means =  np.mean([left_neighbors, right_neighbors], axis=0).reshape((m, 1))
    result = np.concatenate([a, means], axis=1).ravel()
    return result[:-1]  # because the last one had no true right neighbor

a = np.array(range(20))  # simple example
insert_means(a, 5)
```

```
array([ 0. ,  1. ,  2. ,  3. ,  4. ,  4.5,  
        5. ,  6. ,  7. ,  8. ,  9. ,  9.5, 
       10. , 11. , 12. , 13. , 14. , 14.5, 
       15. , 16. , 17. , 18. , 19. ])
```